# How to pass null to external function in Inno Setup

Tags: null, inno-setup

I'm attempting to call a Windows function that takes a PCTSTR parameter (pointer to a string), and want to pass a null.  But using 'Null' raises an exception, and using '0' won't compile.  Is there a way to designate that you want to pass null?

Comment: The equivalent for NULL in PascalScript (used in Inno Setup) is `nil`. It would help if you showed the specific function that you're trying to call, including the code you're using to try to do so, in case there's a different issue, though.

Comment: Ken is right + There's no `PCTSTR` built-in type in Inno Setup. So it all about how you actually declared that type. Show us your code.